# IIS bundles/less cache issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, iis, cache-control

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project that uses `dotless` for parsing/compiling `.less` files and standard bundler for minifying/bundling js files.

The issue is that on production server cache-conrole header is set to `max-age=0, no-cache, no-store` when locally on IIS express it's set to `public` and expires in a year.

Dotless config: `<dotless minifyCss="true" cache="true" web="true" handleWebCompression="false" />`

Bundle config - just includes and `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`

Few web config sections that may help:

```
<staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
...
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="Prerender" type="Prerender.io.PrerenderModule, Prerender.io, Version=1.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web" />
  <add name="OpenSessionInView" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule, Spring.Data.NHibernate32" />
</modules>
...
<handlers>
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <add name="dotless" path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />
</handlers>
```

I tried to add mime maps to `staticContent` section. Also thought about adding request headers in iis, but it works only for files/folders so it likely will not serve bundle.

What have I missed in configs? I appreciate any idea for fixing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you got in your web.config that stuff:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false"/>
```

Comment: Locally it's     `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">` , after deploy on production  -  `<compilation targetFramework="4.5.1">` . I tried both `true` and `false` values - but it didn't help.